# Can't catch Java (Android) Exception with try-catch , createBitmap

Tags: android, exception, android-bitmap

I have a part of code, i use this code four times, but the the sixth time, my application crash , i don't get any Exception or error code. The code is:

```
Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);
```

I try to use:

```
try{

Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);

    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        e.getMessage();
    }catch (OutOfMemoryError o){
        o.printStackTrace();
        o.getMessage();
    }catch (AssertionError a){
        a.printStackTrace();
        a.getMessage();
    } catch ( Throwable t ){
        t.printStackTrace();
        t.getMessage();
    }
```

But nothings happen.   I test my application in diferent dispositives, works fine in a Sony Xperia Z3, Moto G , GenyMotion with different simulators.

But dont works in my Motorola Moto Max.

The log console dont shows an error, but print some codes:

```
  --------- beginning of main
08-11 15:34:55.589    6258-6258/? E/Diag_Lib﹕ Diag_LSM_Init: Failed to open handle to diag driver, error = 2
08-11 15:35:00.638    6275-6275/? E/Diag_Lib﹕ Diag_LSM_Init: Failed to open handle to diag driver, error = 2
    --------- beginning of system
08-11 15:35:00.723     817-1225/? V/AlarmManager﹕ send {ea59bfe, *alarm*:android.intent.action.TIME_TICK}
08-11 15:35:00.723     817-1225/? V/AlarmManager﹕ send {26ca6698, *alarm*:com.google.android.gms/.lockbox.LockboxAlarmReceiver}
08-11 15:35:00.748      817-817/? V/AlarmManager﹕ done {26ca6698, *alarm*:com.google.android.gms/.lockbox.LockboxAlarmReceiver} [26ms]
    --------- beginning of crash
08-11 15:35:00.937    5910-5951/garagecoders.tecnoblinds.main A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2, fault addr 0xaf1f9000 in tid 5951 (AsyncTask #1)
08-11 15:35:00.946      817-817/? V/AlarmManager﹕ done {ea59bfe, *alarm*:android.intent.action.TIME_TICK} [224ms]
08-11 15:35:01.039      348-348/? I/DEBUG﹕ *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
08-11 15:35:01.039      348-348/? I/DEBUG﹕ Build fingerprint: 'motorola/quark_retla/quark_umts:5.0.2/LXG22.33-12.16/16:user/release-keys'
08-11 15:35:01.039      348-348/? I/DEBUG﹕ Revision: 'p4a0'
08-11 15:35:01.039      348-348/? I/DEBUG﹕ ABI: 'arm'
08-11 15:35:01.040      348-348/? I/DEBUG﹕ pid: 5910, tid: 5951, name: AsyncTask #1  >>> garagecoders.tecnoblinds.main <<<
08-11 15:35:01.040      348-348/? I/DEBUG﹕ signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0xaf1f9000
08-11 15:35:01.068      348-348/? I/DEBUG﹕ r0 00000004  r1 af1f8ffc  r2 024760c6  r3 f5d0f000
08-11 15:35:01.068      348-348/? I/DEBUG﹕ r4 b4873340  r5 000061cd  r6 00000247  r7 000002fb
08-11 15:35:01.068      348-348/? I/DEBUG﹕ r8 00000248  r9 00004000  sl 00000000  fp 00003ff0
08-11 15:35:01.069      348-348/? I/DEBUG﹕ ip af1f9000  sp a0f3d078  lr 00000247  pc b5af8014  cpsr 200b0010
08-11 15:35:01.069      348-348/? I/DEBUG﹕ backtrace:
08-11 15:35:01.069      348-348/? I/DEBUG﹕ #00 pc 001bd014  /system/lib/libskia.so (NofilterDXExecutionBuffer::GenerateUpscaleProgram(int, int, int, int)+128)
08-11 15:35:01.069      348-348/? I/DEBUG﹕ #01 pc 001bdcfc  /system/lib/libskia.so (NofilterDXExecutionBuffer::GenerateProgram(int, int, int, int)+92)
08-11 15:35:01.070      348-348/? I/DEBUG﹕ #02 pc 001bddf4  /system/lib/libskia.so (NfDXEBCache::prepareShaderProc32(int, int, int, int)+232)
08-11 15:35:01.070      348-348/? I/DEBUG﹕ #03 pc 001ba4d8  /system/lib/libskia.so (SkBitmapProcState::beginRect(int, int, int)+424)
08-11 15:35:01.070      348-348/? I/DEBUG﹕ #04 pc 001bade8  /system/lib/libskia.so (SkARGB32_Shader_Blitter::blitRect(int, int, int, int)+1244)
08-11 15:35:01.070      348-348/? I/DEBUG﹕ #05 pc 0010616b  /system/lib/libskia.so
08-11 15:35:01.070      348-348/? I/DEBUG﹕ #06 pc 00106237  /system/lib/libskia.so (SkScan::FillIRect(SkIRect const&, SkRegion const*, SkBlitter*)+198)
08-11 15:35:01.070      348-348/? I/DEBUG﹕ #07 pc 00106307  /system/lib/libskia.so (SkScan::FillRect(SkRect const&, SkRegion const*, SkBlitter*)+136)
08-11 15:35:01.070      348-348/? I/DEBUG﹕ #08 pc 001063f7  /system/lib/libskia.so (SkScan::FillRect(SkRect const&, SkRasterClip const&, SkBlitter*)+56)
08-11 15:35:01.071      348-348/? I/DEBUG﹕ #09 pc 000e2037  /system/lib/libskia.so (SkDraw::drawRect(SkRect const&, SkPaint const&) const+258)
08-11 15:35:01.071      348-348/? I/DEBUG﹕ #10 pc 000e3513  /system/lib/libskia.so (SkDraw::drawBitmap(SkBitmap const&, SkMatrix const&, SkPaint const&) const+276)
08-11 15:35:01.071      348-348/? I/DEBUG﹕ #11 pc 000cb863  /system/lib/libskia.so (SkBitmapDevice::drawBitmapRect(SkDraw const&, SkBitmap const&, SkRect const*, SkRect const&, SkPaint const&, SkCanvas::DrawBitmapRectFlags)+530)
08-11 15:35:01.071      348-348/? I/DEBUG﹕ #12 pc 000db98f  /system/lib/libskia.so (SkCanvas::internalDrawBitmapRect(SkBitmap const&, SkRect const*, SkRect const&, SkPaint const*, SkCanvas::DrawBitmapRectFlags)+210)
08-11 15:35:01.071      348-348/? I/DEBUG﹕ #13 pc 00093661  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::SkiaCanvas::drawBitmap(SkBitmap const&, float, float, float, float, float, float, float, float, SkPaint const*)+58)
08-11 15:35:01.071      348-348/? I/DEBUG﹕ #14 pc 0008945d  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
08-11 15:35:01.071      348-348/? I/DEBUG﹕ #15 pc 0089eeff  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat
```

any suggestions ?

Comment: Update: The error was a hardware error, there was nothing todo, at least at that moment.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you are running out of memory for your device, which is why the 6th createBitmap is going to crash your application. Try the following:

```
try{
    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This should properly give output for errors that are thrown. Let me know the output, you might need to manually call System.gc() to handle all the garbage collection youself.

Read this: [Displaying Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html)

Comment: OutOfMemoryError and Exception extends of throwable, must be handled by   }catch(Throwable e) {  }  , i dont have problems with others dispositives like Moto G ....  and Moto MAx, had more ram memory...